# The Adjunction $\_\times A\dashv (\_ )^A$ for Preorders: The Deduction Theorem.

Tags: reference-request, logic, category-theory

The following is from Turi's *Category Theory Lecture Notes*.

> **Definition 11.11** Let $A$ be an object of a category $\mathbb{C}$ with binary products. The right adjoint of $\_\times A:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, if it exists, is denoted by $$(\_ )^A:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$$ and is called the **exponential functor**[.]
>
> [. . .]
>
> One way to denote exponentials $X^A$ is as $A\Rightarrow X$. This stems from a logical reading of the adjunction. Indeed, in a preorder $P$ with meets $\wedge$, if we interpret $\le$ as logical entailment $\vdash\,\,\,$ [. . .] and $\wedge$ as conjunction, then the above adjunction is nothing but the well-known *deduction theorem*:
>   $$\frac{a\wedge b\vdash c}{a\vdash (b\Rightarrow c)}.$$

I would Love to find out more about this and similar phenomena. However, what with a plethora of Logic articles and the like on the Deduction Theorem, I'm not having much luck searching for more information. Help me out, please :)

I have a few pdfs on Categorical Logic I've run some searches through but - besides some cool stuff about the "state monad induced by the adjunction $(\cdot )\times S\dashv (\cdot )^S:\text{Set}\to\text{Set}$" - I got nothing that resembles the above.

Comment: [This is definitely related.](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43281/propositional-logic-with-categories)

Comment: [Here's some decent texts in Categorical Logic.](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53188/decent-texts-on-categorical-logic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the end of Chapter I of *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* by MacLane and Moerdijk. If you're interested in categorical fallouts in logic, it is worth reading further this book (which is basically an introduction to topos theory).

**Edit.** I also once read some lecture notes of Steve Awodey which covers quantifiers as adjunction : [chapter 9, section 9.4 and 9.5](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/80-413-713/notes/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was right in thinking that this is simply [categorical logic](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Categorical_logic); particularly, categorical proof theory. [These notes](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/bob.coecke/AbrNikos.pdf) look ideal.

[Please do correct me if I'm wrong. Further information is welcome of course.]